# Can I use the JAVA API to manage documents?

Tags: marklogic

I want to check-ou, update, check-in my documents via the JAVA API of marklogic. Is this possible? Is there any sample coding available or "getting started"document  on how to do this?

Regards,  Jan van de Klok

Answer (score 1):

Jan:

If it's enough to avoid making an update when another user has changed the document concurrently, you can enable optimistic locking:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_81051

You can also use a multistatement transaction if you want to perform several related changes and have all or none succeed:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_79848

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum

Comment: Hi Erik, simple transactions won't be enough for our application. We really need to version our documents in such a way that users can read published versions of a ducument while other editors are working on higher draft versions of the same document. May I did not made myself clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Out of the box, the Java API doesn't provide such versioning. As Geert suggests, you could use REST extensions to access the MarkLogic DLS functions.  In an approach vaguely similar to RMI, you can create a complementary extension to the Java API to invoke that REST extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is also not very difficult to leverage the [DLS functions](http://docs.marklogic.com/dls) from within custom REST extensions. Adam Fowler did some work on that, and made that available on github:

https://github.com/adamfowleruk/mljs/tree/dev/apps/workplace/rest-api/ext

And here javascript code that shows how to use it, search in it for 'dls', and you should be able to find the relevant part:

https://github.com/adamfowleruk/mljs/blob/dev/src/js/mljs.js

With regard to getting started, I'd recommend looking at the interactive tutorials at:

http://developer.marklogic.com/learn

HTH!